# UIView border cover sub-view?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have a UIView which includes a UIButton which is partially on UIView. I have a problem when I draw a border on my UIView. Please have a look at my screenshot:

[image]

You can see the border is above the UIButton, why? Can anybody suggest? Thanks

Comment: What code do you use to draw the border and add the button?

Comment: you can take a view structure like ContainerView parent of contentView & button. container view will be transparent(clearcolor) and content view will have border and corner. button will be on top of content view. And you will get the exact screen that you want. hope this helps..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490720/subview-appears-underneath-superviews-layer-border/15491068#15491068

Comment: My code is simple. Just inside my view:

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for [aăâ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1847431/aa), I found a solution.

1. Basically the border is always drawn on top of everything
2. What I did is:

   - Create a UIView with color of border
   - Create another UIView as the child the main UIView which is a little bit smaller than the first one. The color of this newly create UIView is the main color

Here is the code:

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
self.backView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

The result is:

[image]

It's more or less what I need although it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It could have to do with the order that the objects are drawn. In your storyboard's "Document Outline", views that are lower down in a view controller's outline are drawn later. Perhaps the button is not the last drawn view, like you want?