# Making an element an element display on top of the UIView border

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to place a `UIButton` inbetween my `popup view` and the `parent view`.

I cant successfully do that by doing that `[self.view addSubview:new];`. My problem there is the border `UIView` can be seen across the `UIButton` .

I've tried  `[self.view.superview addSubview:new];` thinking that that would make it go away but it doesnt it still shows there.

I need to find a way to successfully place that button on top of everything (`UIView` border in this case).

I know I could do that if I insert the button from the `parentView`, but I want to handle all my `subViews` buttons within each `subView`, otherwise it everything will become messy very quickly.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to achieve?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Apple's CALayer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), borders always appear above subviews because they're drawn on another layer. The best solution is to create a background view to fake the border.

So instead, your `popup view` would have an orange background. It'd have another, slightly smaller subview directly over it with a white background, and then your button.

[image: diagram]

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490720/subview-appears-underneath-superviews-layer-border/15491068#15491068) for the implementation.